# Using while(true) a better approach to introduce wait in android background threads

Tags: java, android

How to make a thread wait till another thread has completed its execution in java?
Using while(true) will introduce wait. But is it a good programming practice?

But will it heat up the phone?

Comment: No. Use a monitor and invoke `Object.wait` (or join a thread by invoking `Thread.join`) if you really need to go that low-level. Or use the many high-level synchronization features provided by the Java API (and some specific to Android).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a count down latch (here some pseudo code - meaning I did not compile or run it, it's just for giving an idea).

```
// create the count down latch and initialize it to 1 as we wait for one background thread to finish
final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

// Start the background thread and give it a reference to the count down latch
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable {
   public void run() {
     try {
       // do work here
     } finally {
       cdl.countDown();
     }
   }
}
thread.start();

// We wait till the background thread completes
cdl.await();
```

The benifit is, that is quite high level and we can wait also for multiple things by using different counts.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it is to call:

```
threadThatYouWantToWaitFor.join()
```

in the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Check out:

```
while (true) {
    if (shouldBreakOnSomeCondition()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

versus

```
while (true) {
    if (shouldBreakOnSomeCondition()) {
        break;
    }
    sleep some time
}
```

The first one would be "active" waiting ... and burning a LOT of CPU cycles.

The second thing is less resource consuming; but ideally you would still try to avoid it; using the built-in notification mechanisms; like wait() and notify(); or more advanced ideas like join().

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method wait of class Object.

```
synchronized(obj) {
    while (test) {
        obj.wait();
    }
}
```

And in the other thread

```
synchronized(obj) {
    test = true;
    obj.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: That would cause a `IllegalMonitorStateException` because you can't notify without owning obj's monitor.

Comment: @zapl true.... was a typo, I inserted the notifyAll in the synchronized block. Thanks!